# Location fixing through NFC Tag

Tags: smartphone, geolocation, nfc

I'm new to NFC technologies and I want to develop a smartphone app that reads a NFC tag and sends the location securely to web service. This NFC tag is in a special place and we MUST be sure that the user is in this place at the moment when he scans the tag (must avoid GPS)...

This approach is based on a secure tag that is impossible to clone and someone with his smartphone can't send a fake request to our server.

Is this possible?

Comment: NFC tags can be cloned. As for whether someone can send a fake request, that's up to your server code.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more background on the problem you are trying to solve?  Give us an overview of the process.  As @schroeder mentioned, NFC tags can be cloned, but there are established methods of preventing replay attacks.

Comment: Suppose that client enter to restaurant and take a table. I put NFC tag to this table in order to detect the client table and detect that he is in the restaurant. When client scan tag, I send it throw my smartphone application to my server and validate and answer with some welcome message. After that, I accept receive order from client throw this app.
Now, if someone clone tag, he can send fake order from it's home...

Comment: NFC is not the technology that you are looking for. In order for your use case to work, you would need a 2nd factor to confirm physical location.

Comment: @schroeder thanks for your help. Keeping a well UX throw other technologies which embed security in my case is a bit difficult...